# Call the display method from inside of a method

Tags: java

I am trying write a program that accepts two numbers from a user.

Here's the basic idea of my program:

> Create three methods. One method will add the numbers, one method will multiply the numbers, and the last method will display the numbers.

I tried to call the display method from inside of the first two methods.
But the program isn't displaying the end values.

```
   import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArithmeticMethods {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int num1, num2;
        int sum, mul;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        add( num1, num2);
        multiply(num1, num2);
            }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again.");
                System.out.println("note: text format is an invalid input.");
        }               
        finally{
            input.close();
        }   
}
    public static void add( int num1, int num2) {
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        display(sum,0);
    }
    public static void multiply( int num1, int num2) {
        int mul = num1 * num2;
        display(0, mul);
    }
    public static void display(int sum, int mul) {
        System.out.println("The result after adding the two numbers above is "+ sum +".");  
        System.out.println("The result after multiplying the two numbers above is "+ mul +".");

    }
}


output: Enter the first number: 
5
Enter the second number: 
2
The result after adding the two numbers above is 7.
The result after multiplying the two numbers above is 0.//Is there anyway I can
The result after adding the two numbers above is 0.//get rid of these two lines
The result after multiplying the two numbers above is 10.
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and update your question accordingly

Comment: You're not calling your methods anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call your add and multiply method from your main.

```
public class ArithmeticMethods {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
        double sum, mul;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        add(num1,num2);
        multiply(num1,num2);

            }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again.");
                System.out.println("note: text format is an invalid input.");
        }               
        finally{
            input.close();
        }   

}
    public static void add( int num1, int num2) {
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        display(sum, sum);
    }
    public static void multiply( int num1, int num2) {
        int mul = num1 * num2;
        display(mul,mul);
    }
    public static void display(int sum, int mul) {
        System.out.println("The result after adding the two numbers above is "+ sum +".");
        System.out.println("The result after multiplying the two numbers above is "+ mul +".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the methods you implemented. Try the following after you have read your values in

```
System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
num1 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
num2 = input.nextInt();
//call the your methods using the values read from the user
add(num1, num2);
multiply(num1, num2);
```